# Problems filling SOAP update from VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, soap

I have problem filling Web Service update items

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="https://XXXXXX">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:UpdateRequest>
         <ns:ID>112</ns:ID>
         <ns:UpdateUsername>Testing User</ns:UpdateUsername>
         <ns:UpdateTime>2014-01-01T14:01:59.123</ns:UpdateTime>
         <!--1 to 100 repetitions:-->
         <ns:Option>
            <ns:UpdateID>1234</ns:UpdateID>
            <ns:OptionID>1</ns:OptionID>
            <ns:Status>Progress</ns:Status>
            <ns:EndDate>2015-01-01T14:01:59.123</ns:EndDate>
         </ns:Option>
         </ns:UpdateRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have created VB Class from WDSL and XSD files.
What have i managed to do.

1. Pass Credentials OK
2. Pass Update Request, web Service logged that Testing User has updated (didnt include filled data from Option namespace)

I need help in filling that Option section. Code that i have tryed is as follows

```
Dim Update As New CustomNamespace.UpdateRequestType
            CustomNamespace.ID = "112"
            CustomNamespace.UpdateUsername = "Testing User"
            CustomNamespace.UpdateTime = "2014-01-01T14:01:59.123"

            Using New System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(CustomNamespace)
                Dim Options As New CustomNamespace.OptionType
                Options.UpdateID= "1234"
                Options.EndDate = "2015-01-01T14:01:59.123"
                Options.Status = "Progress"
                Options.OptionID = "1"
            End Using
```

This didnt Work.

All so tryed With out Using command that did send upodate but the Options that had been filled wasent there.
Like this:

```
Dim Update As New CustomNamespace.UpdateRequestType
            CustomNamespace.ID = "112"
            CustomNamespace.UpdateUsername = "Testing User"
            CustomNamespace.UpdateTime = "2014-01-01T14:01:59.123"
Dim Options As New CustomNamespace.OptionType
            Options.UpdateID= "1234"
            Options.EndDate = "2015-01-01T14:01:59.123"
            Options.Status = "Progress"
            Options.OptionID = "1"
```

Im pretty new with code so if something relevant info is missing please ask.

Thanks for any help that comes

Comment: You need to assign the `Options` object to the parent object, like this: `Update.Options = Options`.  Otherwise, even though you've created the `Options` object and filled it in, it won't get sent over the wire because it's not included in the parent object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
Dim Options As New CustomNamespace.OptionType
Options.UpdateID= "1234"
Options.EndDate = "2015-01-01T14:01:59.123"
Options.Status = "Progress"
Options.OptionID = "1"
```

Creates a new instance of the `CustomNamespace.OptionType` class, but it has no relationship to the parent `CustomNamespace.UpdateRequestType` class.  `CustomNamespace.UpdateRequestType` class is what you are sending through the service, so you need to assign the `CustomNamespace.OptionType` to the parent in order for it to be included in what is sent.

Without seeing the WSDL or XSDs, most likely (based on the format of the message) I would expect the `CustomNamespace.UpdateRequestType` class to have a property something like this:

```
Public Option As CustomNamespace.OptionType
```

That is the property you will want to assign your instance of the options class to.  So after you create an instance of `CustomNamespace.OptionType`, you would do this:

```
Update.Options = Option
```

Given the naming of the element (Options) it's possible that it's an array rather than a single instance, but this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsd:element type="tns:UpdateRequestType" name="UpdateRequest"/>
<xsd:element type="tns:UpdateResponseType" name="UpdateResponse"/>
<xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="UpdateFault"/>
<xsd:element type="tns:OptionType" name="Option"/>
-<xsd:complexType name="UpdateRequestType">
-<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element type="xsd:int" name="CustomerID"/>
<xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="UpdateUsername"/>
+<xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="UpdateTime">
<xsd:element maxOccurs="100" minOccurs="1" ref="tns:Option"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
+<xsd:complexType name="UpdateResponseType">
-<xsd:complexType name="OptionType">
-<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element type="xsd:int" name="UpdateID"/>
<xsd:element type="xsd:int" name="OptionID"/>
<xsd:element type="xsd:int" name="Status"/>
-<xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="EndDate">
-<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Date format YYYY-MM-DD</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

That is the code inside the xsd file. There are field for that option that can be presented Max 100 times so its an array ?
When i try to put vlue to that field like this 
CustomNamespace.EndingOption = Options
It gives error Value of type 'CustomNamespace.OptionType' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of CustomNamespace.OptionType'
Is that Dim Options As New CustomNamespace.OptionType line wrong should it have () for array or what.
In Class that has been created from files has those field as follows

Class: UpdateRequestType

```
Private OptionField() As OptionType
```

There are all so own Class

```
'''<remarks/>
        <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Option")>  _
        Public Property Option() As OptionType()
            Get
                Return Me.OptionField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.OptionField = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```